# How do you get the text inside the new HTMLEditor in ASP.Net Ajax Control Toolkit?

Tags: asp.net, ajax

How do you get the text inside the new HTMLEditor in ASP.Net Ajax Control Toolkit?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

controlName.Content will get you the content of the Editor control.